# What it means for a generalized function to be periodic or radially symmetric??

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $T$ be a generalized function. I need to provide definitions for $T$ to be periodic and radially symmetric.

A function (on $\mathbb{R})$is said to be periodic if there exists a $p \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+p)=f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. If $T$ comes from a function then $(T_f,\phi)=\int f(x) \phi(x) dx=\int f(x+p)\phi(x) dx=\int f(x)\phi(x-p) dx=(T_f,\phi(.-p))$

So if I define $(\tau_{p}T)(\phi):=(T,\phi(.-p))$, then I think $T$ will be periodic if there exists a $p$ such that $\tau_{p}T=T$.

Similarly a function is said to be radial if $f(\theta x)=f(x)$ for $\theta$,a rotation. So i expect that if I define $(AT)(\phi)=\frac{1}{det A}(T,\phi(A^{-1}.))$, then $AT(\phi)=T(\phi)$.

Is this alright??

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Yes, these are the right definitions. In the last part, you will want to restrict only to orthogonal matrices, of course.

Comment: Yeah. I meant that only. Thanks

Comment: Please define $\tau_p$ and $A$.